# Async and await methods in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I am creating PCL using MvvmCross.
I am calling one method in **Command** which fetch data by calling web service.
I want to do this data fetch operation asynchronously.
How can I apply **async** and **await** to methods in Command ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1) You can implement the command with an `async void` method/delegate. If you do this, I recommend you have the `async void` method just `await` a `Task` from an `async Task` method that contains the actual logic because `async Task` methods are easier to unit test. Also, you'll need a `try`/`catch` for proper error handling.

2) You can have the command just start a method returning `Task<T>` and expose the result of the operation as a property using [`NotifyTaskCompletion` from my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion). This allows you to data bind to the result as well as errors. However, AsyncEx does not support all the platforms MvvmCross does (in particular, Windows Phone 7.0 and Xamarin.Mac).

**Update - examples:**

Using the first option:

```
public ICommand ContactSlodgeCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new MvxCommand(async () =>
    {
      await ComposeEmailAsync("me@slodge.com", "About MvvmCross and the SQL Bits app", "I've got a question"));
    }
  }
}
```

Using the second option:

```
private INotifyTaskCompletion<MyResource> _resource;
public INotifyTaskCompletion<MyResource> Resource
{
  get { return _resource; }
  set { _resource = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

public ICommand LoadResourceCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new MvxCommand(() =>
    {
      Resource = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(LoadResourceAsync());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Stephen I think your api should include the getting started wiki. Or do you have any blog discussing the api?

Comment: @ShittuOlugbenga: I develop a similar type with examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should do data-binding for that property by using databinding of mvvmcross and use async await or Task like @Stephen Cleary said

```
void FetchData(Action<T> callback)
{
   Task.Run<T>(()=>{
       return Service.GetDataSynchronous();
   }).ContinueWith((data)=>{
       callback(data);
   });
}
public MvxCommand
{
   get 
   {
       return new MvxCommand(()=>{
            FetchData((data)=>{
                this.Property = data;
            });
       });
   }
}
```